# How to have multiple link in Power BI without merger or append

Tags: merge, powerbi

I've 2 tables in my dashboard as below.
How can I control if user in mapping table access the dashboard, only display information for the BookID and StoreID that the person entire to view. 
If user name not in the mapping table, they are allow to view all details table information.

I know this can be control by RLS, but now I having 2 key to link between the table (BookID and StoreID)
Did anyone know how to link without using merge or append ?

*Mapping Table:::* 
UID, UserName, **BookID, StoreID**

*Details Table:::* 
DID, **BookID**, BookName, **StoreID**, StoreName, ReceiptDate, etc....

Comment: It there a relationship connection between the tables?

Comment: Yes, I want when User login, it will only display details information of the bookID and StoreID accordingly in the mapping table.